# Getting Started with SAML and PHP

Tags: php, single-sign-on, saml

I'm beginning work on adding SAML SSO support to a project and am looking for any helpful resources specifically geared towards PHP. I understand the basic concepts and have poked around for any libraries that could help but have come up empty. The only thing I've found is [simpleSAMLphp](https://simplesamlphp.org) which appears to be an entire stack.

Any tips for integrating SAML into an existing project? Bonus points for Zend-Framework related suggestions!

Comment: Google's first page points to this outdated and unanswered question. Best options are now fully available in Packagist: https://packagist.org/search/?q=saml and show integrations to several frameworks. IMHO simpleSAMLphp is a bit of an overkill and not really the best library, yet, is a bit more customizable than others - depends on your use case.

Comment: @OsvaldoM. There's 7 answers, feel free to make it 8

Answer (score 14):

I think that SimpleSAMLPHP is the way to go to make your application act as a full-fledged SAML 2.0 Service Provider. It's indeed a complete stack, but you can narrow down the functionalities to the bare minimum.

From my experience, configuration is a lot simpler than with Shibboleth. This step is simplified with the  configuration website that ships with the distribution package.

The impact on each PHP page is relatively small: http://simplesamlphp.org/docs/1.8/simplesamlphp-sp#section_6

This is the solution we opted for on our Zend environment.

Answer (score 6):

We used [the PHP-SAML toolkit from OneLogin](https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml) for a project that worked used non-transparant proxies (simpleSAMLphp didn't like not knowing the URL it was hosted on).

It is dead simple supporting the most basic login, but SAML 2.0 is a huge spec and it may not support what you want from it (for instance it doesn't support signing Authentication Requests).

Comment: Now the Onelogin php-saml toolkit supports signing/encryptation. Check it

Answer (score 4):

While not a PHP specific solution, maybe [Shibboleth](http://shibboleth.internet2.edu/) will be an acceptable solution for you - it supports both Apache and IIS and can be used with potentially any web framework - java/php/asp.net. This also helps by being a Filter plugin into your webserver so your application will require minimal (if any) modifications to use it

Answer (score 4):

We used [SamlSpBundle](https://github.com/lightSAML/SpBundle) wich we found quite configurable and Symfony2 friendly. If you're not on Symfony2 framework you might look at it's foundation library [lightsaml](https://www.lightsaml.com/) which is a stand-alone.

Answer (score 2):

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.infocard.basics.html has SAML1.0, but SAML has moved on since then...