# Dynamically add options to select with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I'm trying to dynamically add options to a  box using PHP, jQuery and AJAX.

First, a call to AJAX when the first control (taglist) is changed:

```
$('#taglist').change(function(){
    $.post('../includes/ajax.php', {   
      taglist:$(this).find("option:selected").attr('value')}, function(data) {
      $("#catlist").html(data.catlist);
    });
});
```

A PHP function fillselecteditmultiple() I've written populates a sting of the following format:

```
$options = '<option value="1">Option 1</option><option value="2">Option 2</option><option value="3">Option 3</option>';
```

which I return it to the page using json_encode like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['taglist'])){
    $catresult = mysql_query("select catid from category_tags where id='".$_POST['taglist']."'");
    $rowcat = mysql_fetch_array($catresult);

    $catlist = '<select name="cat_id[]" size="5" multiple id="cat_id[]">';
    $catlist .= fillselecteditmultiple(1, 0, $rowcat['catid']);
    $catlist .= '</select>';
    echo json_encode(array("status"=>"success", "catlist" => $catlist));
}
```

I need to return that string ($catlist) inside of a `<select id="mylist"></select>` accordingly so that the final output is this:

```
<select id="mylist">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

In Firebug I see the response correctly but nothing shown in the page.

How should I do this? Please ask for any clarifications if you feel thet my question is incomplete.

Comment: If you're returning a string from your AJAX call, just `append()` it, or set the `html()`.

Comment: Can you show the code you've tried so far please? What exactly "doesn't work"? I don't see any attempt on your part at solving this, or at least explianing what the problem is by posting your failed code.

Comment: downvote seems unnecessary since the question is clear and the OP is willing to post more relevant code.

Comment: @TimJoyce I disagree. [Look at how many questions like this there are](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+select+add).. adding options dynamically to a select box is hardly breaking new ground on SO. This questions is crowd-source debugging. And he's wide open to sql injection. I find it hard to believe someone could be on SO for 2 years with 49 php posts without hearing somewhere about the dangers of sql injection and mysql_*

Comment: My question is far from generic, I'm having specific problems and I'm trying to determine the various options and understand which method to use.

Comment: @bikey77 What you just described is the verbiage behind closing a question as 'Too Localized'

Comment: Also, this is merely a piece of code to get stuff working. In sake of simplicity and in order to make sure that what I;m working on at each time works properly I use a simple POST and dont mind to sanitize it before using it. I really hate when people try so hard to be smart and make others look dumb.

Comment: @bikey77 Security isn't a phase of development, it's something you always strive for.

Comment: I agree. However I prefer to keep the code simple when I post a question on SO so that readers dont bother with other matters apart from the one that i'm actually asking about. Enough said.
As far as your "too localized" comment, you claim this post a sign of effort and research? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094136/getting-started-with-saml-and-php Dont be too quick in judging mate, nobody's flawless, especially those who believe to be.

Comment: @bikey77 Are you kidding me? Your question has been asked thousands of times in slightly different ways. That question was posted before those rules even came into existance. If you have a problem with it flag, downvote, closevote.. whatever. My question may be broad but it's one of only 25 in its field even after 3 years. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+saml

Answer (score 2):

If you have jquery lib running do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'your_script_url.php',
  success: function(data) {
    $('#mylist').html(data);
  }
});
```

alternatively you could append the data if you wanted to add extra options

Answer (score 1):

Use `.append` to insert contents inside an element. See below,

```
$('#mylist').append($options);
```

Comment: Is this given that the response is simply echoed out in the ajax call or returned with json_encode?

Comment: This works if you simply echo the string out in your server side page. However, the variable of $options is probably not available in your javascript code. This answer is merging php and js languages together.

Comment: Unless $options is your js variable.

Comment: I'm not mixing the variables, but if I return it via json_encode nothing appears whereas, if I output some dummytext to a div (for testing/debugging purposes) it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
  success: function(data) {
   //Relevant code
    $('#mylist').html(data);
  }
});
```